AppScript throwing Exception error of Spreadsheets when trying to access Charts present in a Google Sheet
I am running the below code
var reportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWg9ip6iC7wnw9e80IpM6ISKslMbtO591SLoKHTQGms/edit");

var reportStudentGraph = reportSheet.getSheetByName("student_usage_graph");
  
var reportDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RGqWBsUH8vzfDYMf16hIjPJ6fG33BCVQJll_e9fA07k/edit")
 
var body = reportDoc.getBody();

//Get the Student Related Graphs
var student_usage_graphs = reportStudentGraph.getCharts();
Logger.log(student_usage_graphs.length)
  
//Start Writing into the Document
  body.appendParagraph("Academic Delivery and Learning Outcomes Report").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.TITLE)
  
var graph_table = body.appendTable([["",""]]);
graph_table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');  // White for no border

graph_table.getCell(0,0).appendImage(student_usage_graphs[0]);
element = graph_table.getCell(0,0).findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE).getElement().asInlineImage();
element.setHeight(320*element.getHeight()/element.getWidth()).setWidth(320);//ensuring the chart is sized to the table

The above code runs fine till the line where I access the student usage graph while appending the image in the table
graph_table.getCell(0,0).appendImage(student_usage_graphs[0]);

At the above line, I am getting the below error.
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1HWg9ip6iC7wnw9e80IpM6ISKslMbtO591SLoKHTQGms.

This means that there is no problem with accessing the sheet till this line, only when I access the charts I am getting the error.
I have tried making the chart as Blob as an alternative, which again threw the same error when I am exporting the chart as Blob.
When I comment out the line that I have highlighted I can access the spreadsheet and fetch/write other data from the sheets, wherever in the code tries to access the graphs in the spreadsheet I am getting the error above mentioned.
However when the below line is running
Logger.log(student_usage_graphs.length)

I am getting 1.0 as output which means it is detecting that one chart is present in the sheet, but when I access
student_usage_graphs[0]

is where I am getting the error mentioned.
When I am trying other operations on the sheet reportStudentGraph like read or write using getValue and setValue, I am able to read and write without any errors.
Not sure what mistake is happening here.
Can anybody help me on what I am doing wrong here?

Could you try making a copy of script and copy of the spreadsheet and try the new script on  the new spreadsheet url?

@TheMaster I tried changing the chart type it worked. When the chart is Combo Chart of Google Sheets, I am getting this error, if I am using Line Chart of Column Chart, I am not getting error. Now I can't change the chart type for this one issue, how do I overcome it.

@YaskadevaBayari Please provide a minimal reproducible example and also please see how to share a sheet.

I see that you don't have access to this spreadsheet. Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1HWg9ip6iC7wnw9e80IpM6ISKslMbtO591SLoKHTQGms.
Can you check if you have access to this reportSheet spreadsheet?
var reportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWg9ip6iC7wnw9e80IpM6ISKslMbtO591SLoKHTQGms/edit");

I have given the code in the below document. The spreadsheet and the document referred in the code are publicly editable. link

@LimeHusky I have access to the spreadsheet. I am able to read and write from the sheet. I only can't access the combo chart. If the chart is made as Column or Line I am able to access it. My requirement states that the chart has to be a combo chart

The link you have given the same Code as above. Requesting for a  minimal reproducible example especially a copy of sheets for the community to check what's the problem in your question.

Related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055

Thanks @TheMaster . seems like this issue exists in the system, no solution by google too on this

I have experienced the same issue with you. I guess that this might be a bug. At that time, I used the following workaround. This workaround is from Ref and Ref.

Create a Gooels Slide as a temporal file.
Copy a chart from the Spreadsheet to the Slide.
Retrieve an image blob from the Slide.
Put the image blob into the Document.
Delete the temporal file.

In this workaround, the Spreadsheet chart is put into the Document through the Slide. When this workaround is used in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function myFunction() {
  var reportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWg9ip6iC7wnw9e80IpM6ISKslMbtO591SLoKHTQGms/edit");
  var reportStudentGraph = reportSheet.getSheetByName("student_usage_graph");
  var reportDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RGqWBsUH8vzfDYMf16hIjPJ6fG33BCVQJll_e9fA07k/edit");
  var body = reportDoc.getBody();
  var student_usage_graphs = reportStudentGraph.getCharts();
  Logger.log(student_usage_graphs.length)
  body.appendParagraph("Academic Delivery and Learning Outcomes Report").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.TITLE);
  var graph_table = body.appendTable([["", ""]]);
  graph_table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');


  // --- I modified the below script.
  var temp = SlidesApp.create("temp");
  var image = temp.getSlides()[0].insertSheetsChart(student_usage_graphs[0]);
  temp.saveAndClose();
  var chart = image.asImage().getBlob();
  graph_table.getCell(0, 0).appendImage(chart);
  DriveApp.getFileById(temp.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  // ---


  element = graph_table.getCell(0, 0).findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE).getElement().asInlineImage();
  element.setHeight(320 * element.getHeight() / element.getWidth()).setWidth(320);
}

When I tested your showing script using a COMBO chart, I confirmed the same issue. And, when I tested this modified script with the same chart, I confirmed that no error occurred and the chart was correctly put into Document.
Note:

I thought that the following modification might be able to be used.

From
var image = temp.getSlides()[0].insertSheetsChart(student_usage_graphs[0]);
temp.saveAndClose();
var chart = image.asImage().getBlob();


To
var chart = temp.getSlides()[0].insertSheetsChart(student_usage_graphs[0]).asImage().getBlob();




If you use Drive API, you can also use the following modification. If you use Drive API, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.

From
DriveApp.getFileById(temp.getId()).setTrashed(true);


To
Drive.Files.remove(temp.getId());





Reference:

insertSheetsChart(sourceChart) of Class Slide


Thanks @Tanaike for the help. This works

@Yaskadeva Bayari Thank you for replying and testnig it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
